# What do you mean by leaking?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I just know the formal meaning of memory leaking where if we do not use the keyword 'delete' for deleting pointers. But when we perform in the following way why is there a chance of leak?

```
void k()
{
vector<m*>p;
:
:
:
}
```

as far as i know the deletion of the pointers is done automatically by the compiler itself, so is it really necessary that we delete pointers at the end?

Comment: You are not making any pointers point at something allocated with `new`, so there is no leak and no need to delete anything.

Answer (score 3):

> as far as i know the deletion of the pointers is done automatically by the compiler itself

No, it's not. The following is a leak:

```
vector<m*>p;
p.push_back(new m);
```

You'd need to delete the memory yourself:

```
delete p[0]; //in this case
```

The clean alternative is using smart pointers:

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<m> > p;
```

Comment: What are the consequences of memory leak? How would it affect the code?

Comment: @Saikiran you can run out of memory.

Comment: In _no_ case would `unique_ptr` be appropriate.  Think of what happens with `p[0]`.

Comment: In _no_ case would `unique_ptr` be appropriate.  `shared_ptr` perhaps, in a few special cases, but not `unique_ptr`.  If you use `unique_ptr`, `p[i]` will return a reference to it, and any copy from that reference will effectively remove the object from the vector.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you put into `p`. If you just store pointers to something managed elsewhere (or to something not allocated dynamically), there is no leak: the contents of the `vector` will be cleaned up by its destructor.

However, if you do something like `p.push_back(new m);`, and never call `delete` on the elements of `p` before `k` exits, then you're indeed leaking memory. The contents of the `vector` (the pointers) will be cleaned up by its destructor; the memory the pointer point to will not.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you **allocate the contents** of the vector (the `m*`s ) **with `new`** you **WILL** need to **perform `delete`** yourself before you exit the function, if you want to avoid leak. The automatic deletion of vector contents works well **only if the content is a object**, not pointer to a dynamically allocated object.

What you can do is replace `m*` with `std::unique_ptr<m>`. Now the **smart pointer** will **automatically perform `delete`** and you dont need to do anything.

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<m>>p;
```

Alternatively, this is also safe. Since you are storing by value, the contents will be automatically destroyed by the vectors destructor when it leaves the function.

```
vector<m>p;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to address your initial question: There are two related, but distinct notions of memory management errors. I like the terminology used by Valgrind, a popular memory debugger:

- Still reachable memory: This is not strictly a leak, but rather just laziness on part of the programmer. It's unclean, but not necessarily a problem. This happens when you just don't bother to clean something up that you could have cleaned up:

  ```
  int main()
  {
      int * p = new int[100];
  }

  // memory at p is still reachable
  ```

  In such code the "still reachable" allocation is typically in use until the end of the program, and the only sensible point at which to clean up would be at the very end.
- Definitely lost memory: This is your real *leak*. This situation occurs when you lose all references to dynamically allocated memory. That means that you have no way, even in principle, to ever release those resources. This is a serious programming error. If you leak memory in a loop, or in something that is called an arbitrary number of times, your program may very well just die after it's been running for too long, possibly not before making the rest of the OS unusable for a while. Typical code looks like this:

  ```
  int foo()
  {
      int * p = new int[100]();
      return p[20] + 2;
  }   // leak: We lost track of the memory at p

  int main()
  {
      for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
      {
          int * q = new int[line.length() + 1];
          q[0] = foo();  // leak 1
      }                  // leak 2: lost track of the memory at q
  }
  ```

All of the above situations violate the fundamental rule of memory management, formulated first in the 13th century:

> CPU, make me an instrument of your code.
>   Where there is `malloc`, let me write `free`.
>   Where there is `new`, `delete`.
>   Where there is `new[]`, `delete[]`.
>   Enter

As a corollary, we can deduce the *Golden Rule of C++ memory management*, which reduces the risk of memory management bugs dramatically:

> Don't use `new` and never use `delete`. Don't use raw pointers.

The point is that raw pointers don't carry any ownership information about the possible pointee. Thus it is impossible based on a raw pointer alone to decide whether and how any cleaning up may need to be done. This is also the problem with your code -- the answer is simply, "it depends"!

Comment: Your last paragraph is simply wrong.  Most of the time, if smart pointers would do the trick, you shouldn't be using dynamic allocation at all.  There are exceptions, but the most common reason for using dynamic allocation is that the object has a lifetime determined by the application; in such cases, smart pointers don't work.

Comment: @JamesKanze: What exactly is wrong about the last paragraph? If you have something like `unique_ptr` available, then there should be very few reasons to use actual raw pointers. They store the same data, but the smart pointer contains the information about the ownership. And for non-owning collections you can use something like a `std::reference_wrapper`, which again is just a pointer at heart, but with the added information that you *don't* own the object...

Answer (score 0):

The vector itself is fine. It'll manage its own memory automatically and correctly.

The answer therefore depends on what you put in that vector. If you put pointers to heap-allocated objects, it is your responsibility to deallocate those objects when you're done with them. The vector won't do that for you.

If you fail to do that, you'll have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove elements from that vector (using `resize`, `erase` or `clear`), and assuming that `m*` is allocated with `new`, it will NOT use the `delete` operator. Therefore you will have a memory leak. However if those pointers point to a variable on the stack, there will be no memory leak.

EDIT:
You can delete elements before you erase elements from the vector, however if you do a call to resize or clear, you will more than likely not delete all of them (unless you loop and delete before you clear).

Answer (score 0):

The pointers in the vector are not deleted when the vector is deleted. You may use

```
vector<shared_ptr<m>> p
```

if you share the pointers with other parts of your program.

Answer (score 0):

A superficial answer is no: you haven't allocated any memory in
your snippet, so there can be no leak.
A more usable answer would be: it depends on what the role of
the `vector` is, and what you are putting in it.

For starters, if the type `m` has value semantics, and is
copyable, you should be using `vector<m>`, and not `vector<m*>`.
And of course, there's no chance of a leak with `vector<m>`
(assuming that you've implemented `m` correctly).

The most frequent reason for using a vector of pointers, at
least in the application domains I've worked in, is for
navigation between entity objects.  Each entity object manages
its own lifetime, or (less frequently), belongs to some other
entity object which will manage its lifetime.  So there's no
risk of a leak, *but* there is a very significant risk of
a dangling pointer: when the lifetime of a pointed to object
ends, you have to ensure that any pointer to it is removed from
the vector.  (This is usually done by using some variant of the
observer pattern.)

Another reason for using a vector of pointers is that the
contained objects are polymorphic, or large and expensive to
copy.  In such cases, *if* the contained objects contain no
pointers, or you can otherwise prove that cycles would be
impossible, *and* the pointed to objects don't have significant
internal behavior (so there is only very limited use of `this`),
you could make a collection of `std::shared_ptr<m>`; in
practice, Boost's pointer containers are probably a better
solution (and avoid the risks of `std::shared_ptr`).  Both the
`shared_ptr` solution and Boost's pointer containers require
that all elements in the vector be dynamically allocated.